# Does Velocity template has implicit request object?

Tags: spring-mvc, velocity

I'm rephrasing my existing question to a more generic one. I want to know if Velocity has got implicit object references like JSP does.
I'm particularly interested in knowing about the request object.
In JSP we can get the attribute in the request scope like `<%= request.getAttribute("req1") %>`

I know that JSP is a servlet and `<%= request.getAttribute("req1") %>` ends up as a part of _jspService() method which has the request object available to it before the scope of the request ends.

I'm not sure how Velocity works behind the scenes (it may be leaving the request object behind by the time it plays it role)

To test that I did the following thing which was a the part of my previous question.

I have a Spring MVC TestController in which I'm setting a request attribute. I'm using Velocity templates for rendering the views.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView display(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp){
    ...
    req.setAttribute("req1", "This should be present for first request");
    ...
}
```

In the Velocity template I'm doing something like

```
Request: $request.getAttribute('req1')
```

but I'm not getting the value of req1. I know I should have put req1 in model map instead of request but I want to know about implicit request object ref.

I tried `$req1` as well but its not working.

When I'm doing the same thing with the model and returning it back, everything is working correctly.

Where am I going wrong?

**Update:** The same thing is happening with `req.getSession().setAttribute("req1", testObject)` also.

Comment: Just `$req1` doesn't work either?

Comment: Are you able to access the model objects you have set in this method in the velocity template? This syntax seems correct to me...maybe there is some other issue here?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to access model objects properly, @Dave I tried with $req1 also, its not working either!

Answer (score 2):

Salaam,

```
req.getSession().getAttribute("req1", testObject)  ==  $req1
```

AFAIK, you cannot access the request object at VelocityViewServlet's templates, unless you explicity set the request object in context or use a [v-tool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/view/ParameterParser.html) .

Comment: I don't know whether/how VelocityViewServlet is used in Spring MVC. Can you elaborate a little bit more on this?

Comment: Spring doesn't use the VelocityViewServlet, but there should be a VelocityToolsView or something like that in Spring that you can use to support VelocityTools.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question: [Velocity + Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033541/velocity-spring/5066475#5066475).  The Spring folks haven't kept the integration with Velocity very up to date.

Once you've created that extension and set it up to be used properly in your servlet configuration, you'd be able to simply put the object on the ModelAndView and from there do whatever you need with it.